# send file from pc to android mobile via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, mobile, bluetooth

I am developing a desktop application using java to send a file to android devices. I followed this article [sending-files-to-mobile-phone-using-bluetooth-and-obex](http://www.substanceofcode.com/2008/06/20/sending-files-to-mobile-phone-using-bluetooth-and-obex/) to develop it. I tested it in mobile, java based and it works fine but in android mobile I get this exception:

```
Exception: Failed to connect;    
[10051] Une opération a été tentée sur un réseau impossible à atteindre.  
javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: Failed to connect;  
[10051] Une opération a été tentée sur un réseau impossible à atteindre.  
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.connect(Native Method)  
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.access$700(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:44)  
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:651)
```

here there is the code of send:

```
public class SendFile implements Runnable {
private String btConnectionURL;
private byte[] file;
private String filename;

public SendFile (String url, byte[] file, String filename) {
    this.btConnectionURL = url;
    this.file = file;
    this.filename = filename;
}

public void run() {

    try {

        Connection connection = Connector.open(btConnectionURL);
        // connection obtained

        // now, let's create a session and a headerset objects
        ClientSession cs = (ClientSession) connection;



        HeaderSet hs = cs.createHeaderSet();

        // now let's send the connect header
        cs.connect(hs);

        hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, filename);
        hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH, new Long(file.length));

        Operation putOperation = cs.put(hs);

        OutputStream outputStream = putOperation.openOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(file);
        // file push complete

        outputStream.close();
        putOperation.close();

        cs.disconnect(null);

        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a minimum (non)working example.

Comment: Please put some code here. And mark down the lines where are you getting exceptions.

Comment: some code to send a file  :

Comment: I followed this article sending-files-to-mobile-phone-using-bluetooth-and-obex  to develop my application

Comment: ok I edit my post, I add the code. Just an idea I use in may application bluecove library (bluecove 2.1.1 snapshot.jar)

Comment: Please any idea help me